# Eclipse RCP client and redirecting the console to a file

Tags: eclipse, logging, eclipse-rcp

I'm running an Eclipse RCP application. I've enabled the flags *-console -consolelog -debug* and now it's humming along logging to it's console.

However, I'd like it to log to a file. If I start the application from within the Eclipse IDE, I can select a file for it to redirect the console to. There must be some equivalent flag och property I can put in the config.ini file for the exported RCP application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using a logging framework like commons-logging or log4j? If so, those will have options to log to different locations, and that would probably be the best way to manage this.  (It would work the same in all environments).

If you need help setting up a logger in an rcp/OSGi app, take a look at this question:

[Logging in Eclipse/OSGi plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223875/logging-in-eclipseosgi-plugins)