# Eclipse plug-in .log error level configuration option

Tags: logging, eclipse-plugin

I maintain an Eclipse plug-in that was written for Eclipse 3.2.  This plug-in writes information, warnings, and errors to the Eclipse .log file using the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.Status` class

When I run the Eclipse plug-in from within the development Eclipse, with the run configuration of Eclipse Application, the plug-in works fine.  The information, warnings, and errors are written to the Eclipse .log file.

When I package the Eclipse plug-in, and install it in another Eclipse, the information messages aren't written to the .log file.  The warnings and errors are written.

I'm assuming there's some error level logging configuration setting in the Eclipse run configuration that I'm missing when I package the Eclipse plug-in.  I've looked through the Eclipse help and done some Google searches, but I haven't found an answer.

Is there an error level logging configuration setting in Eclipse that I can set when I package my Eclipse plug-in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have a 3.2 system handy and the answer might therefore be not be correct...

But... for 3.7.2 (5 years later!), the Eclipse log system is gated through the OSGi log and thus is configured this way. The `.log` writer is `EclipseLogWriter` and this is configured using a number of Java properties. See `EclipseLogWriter.readLogProperties()` and this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7550991/796559

Comment: I appreciate the response.  I'll test it out today and let you know.

Comment: The answer is to add eclipse.log.level=INFO to the config.ini file.  I had to read the source code of EclipseLogWriter to understand the answer you linked to.  I wish someone would just have documented this somewhere.